# Magento 2 forgotten admin url

Tags: magento2

I am a new Magento and I have forgotten my Magento two admin URL. earlier I was getting an issue with blank admin page which I have fixed but now I have forgotten my admin URL how to get it back.
I know Magento stores it somewhere but am not able to find it.

Please can anyone help me to get back to my URL!
[enter link description here](http://magent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will get it in `env.php` file which you can find under `<magentoroot>/app/etc/`there you will get the url for your store

Answer (score 2):

If you have CLI access there is a bin/magento command for this. See [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-adminurl.html#instgde-cli-displayurl) for more information

```
bin/magento info:adminuri
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get admin route in env.php http://screenshots.collabstar.com/ao/501.png